# How to convert wav to amr on the iOS?

Tags: ios, wav, amr

I found that iOS does not support amr, so I recorded the sound wav format, how to convert wav to amr.If there is a demo best.

Comment: Hello Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11049200/2522457. may be duplicate.